# How to break down strings in a list?

Tags: racket

I am going to determine if any string in a supplies list of strings is longer than a supplied string. I tried to use sting-length to count the length of the string, but it doesn't work. I know cuz los is not a string, but how can I turn LoS -> String. Or I don't need to use string length. I looked at the documentation. There is a list-string function, but the list only contains char.

```
(define LOS-0 '())
(define LOS-1 (cons "POG" LOS-0))
(define LOS-2 (cons "WooooW" LOS-1))
(define LOS-3 (cons "Yee" LOS-2))
(define (any-longer? los)
  (cond
    [(empty? los) '()]
    [(cons? los)
     (if
      (< (string-length (first los) (string-length (rest los))))
      #true
      #false)]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or just recursion:

```
(define (any-longer? s los)
  (cond ((empty? los) #false)
        ((< (string-length s) (string-length (car los))) #true)
        (else (any-longer? s (cdr los)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to see if any element of your list of strings is longer than a given string. The Racket function [`memf`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._memf%29%29) is one easy way to do this, combined with a function that compares string lengths. It returns the tail of the list whose car satisfies a predicate function, or `#f` if none do.

For example,

```lisp
(define (any-longer? los str)
    (if (memf (lambda (s) (> (string-length s) (string-length str))) los)
        #t
        #f))
```

For bonus points: rewrite this to only call `(string-length str)` once, and write your own version of `memf`. (If this is homework the latter might be mandatory)

Comment: Yeah, I think I need to rewrite memf, but now I am struggle with how to break a list into a list of string to compare to other strings. Is there a function in Racket can turn a list to string? qaq

Comment: Why would you want to turn a list into a string?

Comment: Or I don't need to? Since I need to compare the string length of the string with string in the list. In this case, should I break down the code into comparing the supplied string with one string in the list of strings at a time?

Comment: *break down the code into comparing the supplied string with one string in the list of strings at a time?* Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to know if the length any element of a list of strings is longer than the length of a string you have.

To work out if any element of a list of strings is longer than the length of the string:

1. Work out the length of the string, call it `l`.  Now we need to work out whether any element of the list of strings is longer than `l`:

   1. Is the list empty?   If it is then no element of it is longer than `l`.
   2. Is the first element of the list not a string?  If it's not a string this is an error.  This is an optional step but any competent program will include it.
   3. So the first element is a string: Is the length of the first element greater than `l`?  If it is then that element is longer than the string, and we're done.
   4. otherwise, work out whether any element of the *rest* of the list of strings is longer than `l`.  Which you now know how to do!